# Manga set in world full of mercenaries, with various ranks, but the main character is either unranked or low-ranked

Tags: story-identification, manga

This is what I remember of this manga: it starts out explaining that there are mercenaries in the world, and that their power level depends on their rank. The main character is in a school to become a mercenary, and is relatively low-ranked. However, it turns out he is actually one of the people who gives ranks to  others, and that is why he is officially unranked / low-ranked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like *[Gun x Clover](https://myanimelist.net/manga/39281/Gun_x_Clover)*.

[image]

> Mikado High School trains the best students to be the best mercenary bodyguards. But Morito Hayama, a merc escort student with no rank whatsoever, is suddenly assigned to guard a person so highly valued that no escort has ever survived before. Will his subject survive the experience? Will he survive?!

The main character, Morito Hayama, attends a high school where the teachers and students are all mercenaries with assorted ranks. He's an unassuming-looking boy with no rank himself, but he has the ability to promote and demote the other mercenaries, which makes him more powerful than any of them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a SFF manga?

Comment: I think it just about is SFF, but it's borderline. There's no futuristic technology, and there's very little in the way of overt magic or supernatural elements (based on what I've seen in the first couple of chapters). However, one of the main characters has Disassociative Personality Disorder, and certain things about her (like her hair colour, and a roman numeral tattooed on her chest) change when she shifts from one personality to another. Also, there's another mercenary who is nearly blind, but has an "Echo-Location-Skill" and can hear people's heartbeats.